# org.apache.flink.api.table.TableException: "Alias on field reference expression expected"

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am using Apache Flink's Table API on the 1.1-SNAPSHOT version to evaluate SQL queries on streams.

Following is my code:

```
private static final int MAX_RACK_ID = 10;
private static final long PAUSE = 100;
private static final double TEMP_STD = 20;
private static final double TEMP_MEAN = 80;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
     StreamExecutionEnvironment env=StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
     env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
     StreamTableEnvironment tableEnv=TableEnvironment.getTableEnvironment(env);

     DataStream<MonitoringEvent> dstream = env.addSource(new MonitoringEventSource(MAX_RACK_ID, PAUSE, TEMP_STD, TEMP_MEAN));
     tableEnv.registerDataStream("TemperatureData", dstream,"rackid,temperature,timestamp");

     Table tab1 = tableEnv.sql("select STREAM rackid,temperature,timestamp from TemperatureData where temperature>=100");
     DataStream<TemperatureEvent>tempstream=tableEnv.toDataStream(tab1, TemperatureEvent.class);
     tempstream.print();
}
```

When I execute this program, it throws the following exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.api.table.TableException: Alias on field reference expression expected.
    at org.apache.flink.api.table.TableEnvironment$$anonfun$4.apply(TableEnvironment.scala:299)
    at org.apache.flink.api.table.TableEnvironment$$anonfun$4.apply(TableEnvironment.scala:292)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:108)
    at org.apache.flink.api.table.TableEnvironment.getFieldInfo(TableEnvironment.scala:292)
    at org.apache.flink.api.table.StreamTableEnvironment.registerDataStreamInternal(StreamTableEnvironment.scala:212)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.table.StreamTableEnvironment.registerDataStream(StreamTableEnvironment.scala:130)
    at com.yash.flink.Program.main(Program.java:31)
```

I have a few questions:

- What is the way to write SQL queries on streams using Apache Flink's Table API?
- How can I implement this query in Flink?
- Is this a bug in Flink's Table API ??

Comment: StreamSQL is an unreleased feature of Apache Flink. Stack Overflow is not a good place to ask questions about SNAPSHOT versions since these are very ephemeral and questions about these versions are not very helpful for others. It is better to directly interact with the developer community in such cases, e.g., by posting a mail to the mailing list or opening a bug report.

Comment: Ok..What is the official release date of Flink 1.1 version ?? Will it include support for Stream SQL ??

Comment: The exact release date depends on the Apache Flink community. A discussion about cutting a release in the next weeks was started recently. Everything in the current master branch will be part of the release (including Stream SQL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You found a limitation / bug in the Table API. The problem is caused by the registration of the `DataStream<MonitoringEvent>` as a table. You should do

```
tableEnv.registerDataStream(
  "TemperatureData", 
  dstream,
  "rackid AS rackid, temperature AS temperature, timestamp AS timestamp"
);
```

to make it work. I will make sure that the problem is fixed before Stream SQL is released in Flink 1.1.0.

Comment: Your solution helped me solved that problem.But after that another exception occured : `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.calcite.tools.FrameworkConfig.getTraitDefs()Lorg/apache/flink/shaded/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList;
 at org.apache.flink.api.table.FlinkPlannerImpl.<init>(FlinkPlannerImpl.scala:50)
 at org.apache.flink.api.table.StreamTableEnvironment.sql(StreamTableEnvironment.scala:127)
 at com.yash.flink.Program.main(Program.java:31)` ..Is this an issue in calcite ?? Can you please provide solution for this ?? The method present in calcite

Comment: Looks like a version conflict to me. Does your project depend on Guava?

Comment: No,I haven't added any Guava dependency in my project.I do see that Flink Table API uses guava version 18.0.I am using calcite version 1.7.0.

Comment: If I use calcite version 1.8.0,I get the following exception : `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.calcite.tools.RelBuilder.scan(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/calcite/tools/RelBuilder;
 at org.apache.flink.api.table.plan.logical.CatalogNode.construct(operators.scala:389)
 at org.apache.flink.api.table.Table.getRelNode(table.scala:66)
 at org.apache.flink.api.table.StreamTableEnvironment.registerDataStreamInternal(StreamTableEnvironment.scala:223)
 at org.apache.flink.api.java.table.StreamTableEnvironment.registerDataStream(StreamTableEnvironment.scala:130)`

Comment: I think we should move this discussion to the Flink mailing list. SO comments is not the right place to debug issues of unreleased software. Thanks

Comment: FYI: https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/2209 should solve your issues.